# A custom stripe checkout form using my own advanced settings for the various payment options

Tags: php, paypal, stripe-payments

OK with as much detail I can offer I am trying to get the strip checkout form to work with my own advanced settings. Meaning in my admin panel on my website I can add set or adjust prices from there. I will provide photos and code.

Below is a sample of the PayPal form code. I use Button Code Variables as you see to work with different prices and product I set.

Code Variables example = [`merchant_id] [item_name] [amount] [item_number] [user_id] [return] [notify] [merchant_button]`

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="[merchant_id]">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="[item_name]">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="[amount]">
  <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="[item_number]">
  <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="[user_id]">
  <input type="hidden" name="return" value="[return]">
  <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="[notify]">
  <input type="image" src="[merchant_button]" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

I need the stripe checkout form to work in the same way some how. The image below is the Sales Packages for the products. Also overtime I add a product like in the image below a button is automatically added to the members sales page.

[image: This is the Sales Packages i create for the products]

This is where the form code needs to go that creates the button and checkout.

[image: This is where the form code will go]

And this is the Code Variables that that need to go into the form values to make the form checkout work with each price or product.

I have forms that i have tried from stripe below.

```
<!-- Load Stripe.js on your website. -->
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3"></script>
<!-- Create a button that your customers click to complete their purchase. Customize the styling to suit your branding. -->
<button
style="background-color:#6772E5;color:#FFF;padding:8px 12px;border:0;border-radius:4px;font-
size:1em"
id="checkout-button-price_1H2XkYEESdtcMolQIxkRKapX"
role="link"
type="button"
>
Checkout
</button>
div id="error-message"></div>

<script>
  (function() {
    var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh');
    var checkoutButton = document.getElementById('checkout-button-price_1H2XkYEESdtcMolQIxkRKapX');
    checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
      stripe.redirectToCheckout({
        lineItems: [{price: '[amount]', quantity: 1}], //<---- I put a Variable [amount] to show amount from Sales Packages
        mode: 'payment',
        successUrl: window.location.protocol + 
          '//proadtraffic.com/success',
        cancelUrl: window.location.protocol + 
          '//proadtraffic.com/canceled',
      })
      .then(function (result) {
        if (result.error) {
          var displayError = document.getElementById('error-message');
          displayError.textContent = result.error.message;
        }
      });
    });
  })();
</script>
```

I need to be able to put the following Code Variables --> `[merchant_id] [item_name] [amount] [item_number] [user_id] [return] [notify]` <-- into the stripe checkout form so that it will pick up each price button a user clicks on that i have set from the Sales Packages page from my admin like you seen with the PayPal.

I have tried for several days and i would like to get the right form and script that will work in a similar way. Maybe i am using the wrong code from  and script from stripe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using "client only" (that is, Javascript-only) Checkout, you can **only** pass in a known Price object, not a dynamic price:

https://stripe.com/docs/js/checkout/redirect_to_checkout#stripe_checkout_redirect_to_checkout-options-lineItems

What this means is that you **cannot** pass in the item's amount from your frontend Javascript. Instead, you have to [create a Product + Price in the Stripe Dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/products), and then reference the Price's ID in your button code:

```
(function() {

var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh');
var checkoutButton = document.getElementById('checkout-button-price_1H2XkYEESdtcMolQIxkRKapX');

checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
  stripe.redirectToCheckout({
    lineItems: [{price: 'price_1H2XkYEESdtcMolQIxkRKapX', quantity: 1}],
    mode: 'payment',
    successUrl: window.location.protocol + '//proadtraffic.com/success',
    cancelUrl: window.location.protocol + '//proadtraffic.com/canceled',
  })
  .then(function (result) {
    if (result.error) {
      var displayError = document.getElementById('error-message');
      displayError.textContent = result.error.message;
    }
  });
});

})();
</script>
```

What you can do, however, if you want a variable amount that you can pass in from the frontend is create a $1 Price (for example) and then set the quantity as needed for each product you sell. I'd recommend either using the [client-server approach](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/accept-a-payment) which allows for dynamic pricing, or creating a Price for thing you sell and passing the Price ID as shown above.

Unlike the PayPal button, this approach prevents your customers from editing the web form and giving themselves a discount (for example)—Stripe allows only known prices in Checkout.